# Сохранение промежуточных результатов

Tags: php, yii2

Я пытаюсь заюзать GridView. Данные подтягиваю для каждого столбца отдельно лямбдой. Проблема в следующем: для нескольких столбцов я получаю одни и те же связанные данные, например:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Article::find()
    ]),
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'user name',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->getUser()->name;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'user email',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->getUser()->email;
            },
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Т.е. получается два запроса юзера, хотя хватило бы и одного. Учитывая то что это лишь пример, на самом деле запросов еще больше - это сильно бьет по скорости. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте "жадную загрузку"

```
'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Article::find()->with('user')
]),
```

А если вы хотите что бы работала фильтрация и сортировка в **GridView**, то вместо **with()**, можете использовать **joinWith()**